# Using Cypress Typescript types

Tags: typescript, integration-testing, typescript-typings, cypress

I'm trying to setup TypeScript with Cypress. The environment seems to be setup well, but there seems to be an issue around pulling in type definitions from Cypress.

For deconstructing the `cy.wait('@graphql').then({request})` params, TypeScript complains that you have to set the type of the `request` param. There doesn't seem to be a lot of type exports from Cypress, but there is  `Cypress.WaitXHR` and `Cypress.ObjectLike` that allow me to hack my way to a solution.

```
import Cypress from 'cypress';

type WaitXHR = Cypress.WaitXHR;
type ObjectLike = Cypress.ObjectLike;

describe('Admin Page', () => {
  it('Visits admin page', () => {
    cy.server()
      .route({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'https://www.example.com/graphql',
      }).as('graphql');

    cy.visit('/');

    cy.wait('@graphql').then((xhr: WaitXHR) => {
      const { request }: { request: ObjectLike} = xhr;
      expect(request.body.operationName).to.equal('initalSetup');
    });
  });
```

This solution seems to appease TypeScript, but doesn't feel very nice. **Is there a better way to do this?**

Comment: I hunted this in the node_modules and found cypress.d.ts for 'request' and also found defining this particular type - WaitXHR and ObjectLike. For now thats the only option. Shame it doesn't utilise other types like node request.

Answer (score 1):

I've done it like this, though I don't like using 'any' its much tidier.

```js
import Cypress from 'cypress';
type ObjectLike = Cypress.ObjectLike;

interface WaitXHRCustom {
  request: ObjectLike;
  response: ObjectLike;
}

cy.wait(`@${aliasRequest}`).should((xhr: any) => {
  const { request, response } = xhr as WaitXHRCustom;
```